# how to access partition of file based file system?

Tags: filesystems, partition, btrfs

I've created 2GB file

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=2.0G.fs bs=1024 count=2097152
```

I've created two GPT partitions on this file using `cfdisk`, now the situation is following:

```
$ fdisk -l 2.0G.fs
Disk 2.0G.fs: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 87EEF449-2FC2-6F4F-970B-F8B06CDA9C5F

Device       Start     End Sectors  Size Type
2.0G.fs1      2048 3123199 3121152  1.5G Linux filesystem
2.0G.fs2   3123200 4194270 1071071  523M Linux filesystem
```

Now I would like to format 1.5G parition to btrfs. How can I do this? In block devices I would do something like `mkfs.btrfs -L disk /dev/sda1` but how can I access partition stored in file?

**EDITED:**

I've tried mount it as a loop device with `-P, --portscan` options
`$ sudo losetup -P /dev/loop4 /mnt/hgfs/VMware_shared_folder/btrfs/2.0G.fs`

and seems it created those devices which I can access

```
$ ll /dev/loop4*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   7, 4 Feb  7 14:15 /dev/loop4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Feb  7 14:15 /dev/loop4p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 Feb  7 14:15 /dev/loop4p2
```

but `mkfs.btrfs` shows following so I'm in doubt if I did everything OK because according to [this](https://linuxhint.com/install-and-use-btrfs-on-ubuntu-lts/) tutorial `mkfs.btrfs` should work without error.

```
$ mkfs.btrfs /dev/loop4p1
btrfs-progs v4.15.1
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

probe of /dev/loop4p1 failed, cannot detect existing filesystem.
ERROR: use the -f option to force overwrite of /dev/loop4p1
```

Comment: I think you have to mount the file (**loop mount**). I won't add more as I would have to look it up. I bolded the search terms.

Comment: `mkfs.btrfs /dev/loop4p1` works as expected here (but I partitioned with `gdisk`). Maybe add `-f`?

Comment: It seems that mkfs sees something on the loop device that looks like a filesystem signature. Did you try `-f`?